# how to parse a JSON String with jq (or other alternatives)?

Tags: json, string, sed, escaping, jq

I'm trying to get `jq` to parse a JSON structure like:

```
{
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : "{\"id\":\"9ee ...\",\"parent\":\"abc...\"}\n"
}
```

That is, an element in the JSON is a string with escaped json.

So, I have something along the lines of
`$ jq [.c] myFile.json | jq [.id]`

But that crashes with `jq: error: Cannot index string with string`

This is because the output of .c is a string, not more JSON.
How do I get jq to parse this string?

My initial solution is to use sed to replace all the escape chars (`\":\"`, `\",\"` and `\"`) but that's messy, I assume there's a way built into `jq` to do this?

Thanks!

edit:
Also, the jq version available here is:

```
$ jq --version
jq version 1.3
```

I guess I could update it if required.

Comment: This question also helps if you are looking for: "How to unescape json string using jq?"

Answer (score 327, accepted):

jq has the [`fromjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Convertto/fromJSON) builtin for this:

```
jq '.c | fromjson | .id' myFile.json
```

`fromjson` was added in version 1.4.

Comment: Thank you. This works.
I'll accept this answer, as it's more 'idiomaitic' I feel.

Cheers.

Comment: @ColinGrogan please do.

Comment: @ColinGrogan: I don't see any reason to change the accepted answer since you clearly wrote in your question that you used the version 1.3 of jq in which the `fromjson` feature isn't available. In other words, even if this answer is interesting, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Is it possible to use this but on an entire json file (not specifying the .id property)?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain yes, either omit it or use dot: `jq 'fromjson | .' myfile`, where myfile contains `"{\"key\":1, \"word\":\"cat\"}"`

Answer (score 82):

You can use the raw output (-r) that will unescape characters:

```
jq -r .c myfile.json | jq .id
```

ADDENDUM: This has the advantage that it works in jq 1.3 and up; indeed, it should work in every version of jq that has the -r option.

Comment: -r is much easier than the accepted answer. You got my upvote. I use jq to view json from my clipboard. So when I run into this I do: `pbpaste | jq -r`

Comment: bonus: if you want to escape quotes you can use sed: `pbpaste | sed -e 's/\\\"/\"/g'`. this helps when you have escaped json that contains escaped json. Take out the first level of escaped quotes with sed and then jq can remove the last level. e.g `pbpaste | sed -e 's/\\\"/\"/g' | jq -r`

Answer (score 2):

**Motivation**: you want to parse JSON string -  you want to escape a JSON object that's wrapped with quotes and represented as a String buffer, and convert it to a valid JSON object. For example:

some **JSON unescaped string** :

```
"{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"position\":\"developer\"}"
```

the **expected result** ( a JSON object ):

```
{"name":"John Doe","position":"developer"}
```

**Solution**: In order to escape a JSON string and convert it into a valid JSON object use the `sed` tool in command line and use regex expressions to remove/replace specific characters:

```
cat current_json.txt | sed -e 's/\\\"/\"/g' -e 's/^.//g' -e 's/.$//g'
```

`s/\\\"/\"/g` replacing all backslashes and quotes ( `\"` ) into quotes only (`"`)

`s/^.//g` replacing the first character in the stream to none character

`s/.$//g` replacing the last character in the stream to none character

Comment: I had a similar problem. Used the same sed command verbatum. Bravo! Pipe that result to `jq -r` and you can process escaped json inside your json.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: trying to parse JSON with `sed`. Any tool that tries to match just a few of the most common escapings is going to miss others (for example, you're handling `"` but not `\t`)

Comment: I had to also replace double quote characters: `cat a.json | sed -e 's/\\\"/\"/g' -e 's/^.//g' -e 's/.$//g' -e 's/""/"/g' | jq `