# Parsing nested json with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am parsing a nested json to get specific values from the json response. The json response is as follows:

```
{ 
"custom_classes": 2,
"images": 
    [ 
      { 
        "classifiers": 
        [ 
          { 
            "classes": 
            [ 
              { 
                "class": "football",
                "score": 0.867376 
              } 
            ], 
            "classifier_id": "players_367677167",
            "name": "players" 
          } 
        ], 
        "image": "1496A400EDC351FD.jpg" 
      } 
    ], 
"images_processed": 1 
}
```

From the class images=>classifiers=>classes:"class" & "score" are the values that I want to save in a csv file. I have found how to save the result in a csv file. But I am unable to parse the `images` alone. I can get `custom_classes` and `image_processed`.

I am using `jq-1.5`.

The different commands I have tried :

```
curl "Some address"| jq '.["images"]'
curl "Some address"| jq '.[.images]'
curl "Some address"| jq '.[.images["image"]]'
```

Most of the times the error is about not being able to index the array `images`.

Any hints?

Comment: Template answer: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry i missed to add the commands i tried. Edit

Comment: For extracting JSON embedded in a JSON string, see instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154684/how-to-parse-a-json-string-with-jq-or-other-alternatives (TLDR: `jq '.field | fromjson'`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I must say, I'm not terribly good at `jq`, so probably all those array iterations could be shorthanded somehow, but this yields the values you mentioned:

```
cat foo.json | jq ".[] | .images | .[] | .classifiers | .[] | .classes | .[] | .[]"
```

If you want the keys, too, just omit that last `.[]`.`

**Edit**
As @chepner pointed out in the comments, this can indeed be shortened to

```
cat foo.json | jq ".images[].classifiers[].classes[] | [.class, .score] | @csv "
```

Comment: `.images[].classifiers[].classes[]` should be fine, at least in version 1.5 (which, honestly, has probably been out long enough that if people aren't using it, they should upgrade). The output of that filter could be piped through `[.class, .score] | @csv` to produce the desired CSV output.

Comment: @chepner: is it not possible that i access both the variables in the single line?  `cat foo.json | jq '.images[].classifiers[].classes[]{.score,.class}' `?? I have tried differnt combinations. I am following the sample from a tutorial website.

Comment: @Vini, perhaps try this: `cat foo.json | jq '.[] | .images[].classifiers[].classes[] | {foo: .score, bar: .class}'`, you need to provide the object-keys to use in the newly constructed object. Or use `[.score, .class]` to make it an array.

Comment: @OliverBaumann: i found it. I was trying all possibilities :)

Comment: @OliverBaumann : it did not work with the ` .[ ] ` in the initial place. The command from chepner simply works as well.

Answer (score 2):

**jq** solution to obtain a prepared *csv* record:

```
jq -r '.images[0].classifiers[0].classes[0] | [.class, .score] | @csv' input.json
```

The output:

```
"football",0.867376
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the data this filter which uses [Recursive Descent: ..](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..), [objects](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars) and [has](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#has(key)) may work:

```
.. | objects | select(has("class")) | [.class,.score] | @csv
```

Sample Run (assuming data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -Mr '.. | objects | select(has("class")) | [.class,.score] | @csv' data.json
"football",0.867376
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/0qDy0fI_fZ)

Here is another variation which uses [paths](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#paths,paths(node_filter),leaf_paths) and [getpath](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#getpath(PATHS))

```
getpath( paths(has("class")?) ) | [.class,.score] | @csv
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/cLAeCsoIY9)