# Relate elements in table form from Json file with jq

Tags: json, jq, tabulate

I'm new to `jq` and I have the following code to obtain tabulated the values for each element called `Abc`:

```
["Abc"], ( .. | objects | select(has("Abc")) | [.["Abc"]] ) | @tsv
```

This is the current output I get:

```
"Abc"
"4"
"2"
"1"
"9"
"3"
"2"
"4"
"9"
```

I would like to add 4 columns to the left to show for each `Abc` value the corresponding page, row and column. Additionally if possible as first column add a counter from 1 to number of "Abc" elements.

Below I show the current output, compared with the desired output and the structure of the Json file in order to clarify:
[image]

The input Json file is below:

```
{
  "document": {
    "page": [
      {
        "@index": "0",
        "image": {
          "Abc": "4"
        }
      },
      {
        "@index": "1",
        "row": [
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "2"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "9"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "3"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@index": "2",
        "row": [
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "2"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "4"
                }
              },
              {
                "text": {
                  "Abc": "9"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses `paths` and has several advantages, including brevity, simplicity, and that it can easily be adapted to a handle data that is in a different format.

For clarity, we begin by defining a function that adds the row numbers:

```
# add a sequential id, starting at 1
def tsvRows(s):
  foreach s as $s (0; .+1; [.] + $s)
  | @tsv;

(["counter", "page", "row", "column", "Abc"] | @tsv),
tsvRows(paths as $p
  | select($p[-1] == "Abc")
  | getpath($p) as $v
  | $p
  | .[2] as $page
  | (if .[3] == "row" then .[4] else null end) as $row
  | (if .[5] == "column" then .[6] else null end) as $column
  | [$page, $row, $column, $v] )
```

Comment: You´re rigth, this solution is less complex hehe. I have a question, if there are more elements within the block `"text" {}`, for example `"text": {"Abc": "4" \n "Def": "5" \n "Ghi": "2"}` How to adapt your code to look for more elements? something like `select($p[-1] == ["Abc", "Def", "Ghi"])` or how would be?

Comment: I’d suggest reading up on jq, and if you then can’t figure it out, by all means ask a separate, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The irregularity of the input data makes the requirements a little opaque, but the following produces the desired output.

```
["counter", "page", "row", "column", "Abc"],
(foreach (.document.page[] | objects) as $page ({page: -1, counter: 0};
  .page += 1
  | if ($page | (has("image") and (.image|has("Abc"))))
    then
      .counter +=1
      | .out = [.counter, .page, null, null, ($page|.image.Abc)]
    else foreach ($page | .row[]?) as $row (.row=-1;
      .row += 1
      | foreach ($row | .column[]) as $column (.column=-1;
          .column +=1
          | foreach ($column | .text | objects) as $x (.;
              .counter += 1
              | .out = [.counter, .page, .row, .column, $x["Abc"]]
              ; . )
           ; . )
      ; . )
    end
    ; .out )
)
| @tsv
```

### Output

Specifically, with the -r command-line option, the output produced from the given input is as follows (tabs included):

```
counter page    row column  Abc
1   0           4
2   1   0   0   2
3   1   1   0   1
4   1   1   1   9
5   1   2   0   3
6   2   0   0   2
7   2   1   0   4
8   2   1   1   9
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. The output is correct only could you help me to add in output the column for element `column` like shown on image, this is the red elements

Comment: `column` is now included too.

Comment: It works just amazing! Thanks a lot peak. What is the logic behind the use of `|`? I see very often in your code. Does it work like in bash when you pass the output of a command to another command with `|`? For example `ls -1 | sort | uniq`

Comment: Yes, it's the "pipe" symbol used to form a "pipeline".