# List key values of JSON file using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have JSON file like the below; I need to list only x or y values only using jq:

```
{  
   "x":[  
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
   ],
   "y":[  
      "d",
      "e"
   ]
}
```

I need to get only x values like

```
a
b
c
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: @abhi314 jq is not jQuery!

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the update

Comment: Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154684/use-jq-to-parse-a-json-string

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
cat input.json | jq '.x[]'
```

- `.x`: get value of `x` property
- `[]`: access array elements

If you want it as a valid JSON array, remove the `[]` part: `.x`. `--raw-output`/`-r` outputs top-level strings without quotation marks, e.g.:

```
$ jq '.x' < input.json
[  
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]

$ jq '.x[]' < input.json
"a"
"b"
"c"

$ jq -r '.x[]' < input.json
a
b
c
```

[Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/gHy_uOH0Yi)