# How do I parse JSON log file with jq?

Tags: json, filter, jq

I have two types of logs in a JSON log file and I want to parse and label each event with a tag using a jq filter. An example of each event below:

The goal is to label each event so that if message begins with a TR, .sourcetype=application_log, else if message begins with an IP, .sourcetype=access_log.

So far, I'm working with this: test.log jq -r '.[] | select(.log[12:14] == "TR") | .sourcetype = "application_log" | .sourcetype'

```
{
"log": "{\"message\":\"TR=failed to send order confirmation to \\\"someone@example.com\\\": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \\\"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.64.5.235:5000: i/o timeout\\\"\",\"severity\":\"warning\",\"timestamp\":\"2019-07-23T00:47:07.216693578Z\"}\n",
"stream": "stdout",
"time": "2019-07-23T00:47:07.222368843Z"
}

{
"log": "{\"message\":\"IP=failed to send order confirmation to \\\"someone@example.com\\\": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \\\"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.64.5.235:5000: i/o timeout\\\"\",\"severity\":\"warning\",\"timestamp\":\"2019-07-23T00:47:07.216693578Z\"}\n",
"stream": "stdout",
"time": "2019-07-23T00:47:07.222368843Z"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jq to parse a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154684/use-jq-to-parse-a-json-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the task correctly, a solution would be:

```
.log[12:14] as $code    
| if ($code == "TR") then .sourcetype = "application_log"
  elif ($code == "IP") then .sourcetype = "access_log"
  else .
  end
```

If you want the .log values as JSON objects so you can add the .sourcetype there, you would have to use `fromjson` on the original .log values, along the lines of:

```
.log |= fromjson
| .message[0:2] as $code    
| if ($code == "TR") then .log.sourcetype = "application_log"
  elif ($code == "IP") then .log.sourcetype = "access_log"
  else .
  end
| .log |= tostring . # is this line really needed?
```