# How to parse with jq a json encoded as string inside a json

Tags: json, jq

There is any way to get parse this json with jq within a single command? I would like to do something like this: `jq .key.first`. But yea, taking into consideration that the `key` is a string and need to be first parsed to json.

```json
{
  "key": "{\"first\":\"123\",\"second\":\"456\"}"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to parse a JSON String with jq (or other alternatives)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154684/how-to-parse-a-json-string-with-jq-or-other-alternatives)

Answer (score 11):

Use `fromjson`, e.g.

```
jq '.key|fromjson|.first'
```

As pointed out in a comment, this can be abbreviated by omitting the last pipe character.

In general, it’s better to avoid calling jq twice when one call is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> There is any way to get parse this json with jq within a single command?

It depends on how you define a single command. It can be done using a pipeline that contains two invocations of `jq`:

```sh
INPUT='{
  "key": "{\"first\":\"123\",\"second\":\"456\"}"
}'

echo "$INPUT" | jq -r .key | jq .
```

`jq -r .key` tells `jq` to echo the raw value of `.key`, not its JSON representation (it is a string, normally `jq` outputs it as it is represented in the input JSON).

The output is:

```sh
{
  "first": "123",
  "second": "456"
}
```

The second invocation of `jq` (`jq .`) doesn't do anything to the data; it just format it nicely (as depicted above) and coloured (it does not colour the output if it does not go to the terminal).

However, it shows that its input is a JSON (the raw value of `.key`) that can be processed further. You can, for example, use `jq .first` instead to get `"123"` (the string encoded as JSON) or `jq -r .first` to get `123` (the raw value).

Comment: I was trying to do within a single jq command instead of using a pipe. But yea, this works too. Thanks!

Comment: this solves too: `jq -r '[.key|fromjson][0].first'`

Comment: Indeed. I didn't know about `fromjson`. It does not need to be wrapped into an array. `jq -r '.key|fromjson.first` is enough.

Comment: Indeed, I was following an example, my bad.